# Custom Methods for an Array of Custom Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array of type `Library`, where I can store many objects of type `Library` that I'll manage later. Before I get too deep, I am trying to make a `print()` method on the array so that I can simply call `myLibrary.print()` to print the array.

```
public class Library {
    // Constructor

    public Library() {
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Library Sorted by Title");
    }
}

public class MediaManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Library myLibrary[] = new Library[100];
        myLibrary.print();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error saying that there is no `print()` on `Library[]`.

How would I go about printing this array? Would I just loop through the array in the main file and call a separate print on each object? If this is the case, where would I write custom methods to sort the array?

**UPDATE**

Requirements from my assignment: 
"Your program will use one array of type Library to store all information read from the input file."

"At the top level you will have a class called Library. Library will have three subclasses: Music, Book, and Movie. Music will have two subclasses: Song and Album. Book will have two subclasses: Fiction and Nonfiction. Movie, Fiction, Nonfiction, Song, and Album will not have any subclasses."

**UPDATE 2**

This is for a CS-101 course. I don't feel I should need to use Comparable.

Comment: Do you want to manage a set of Libraries, or do you want to manage Books/Titles within one Library? Means, do you have one Library with many Titles or do you have many Libraries (possibly again with many Titles)?

Comment: Here is the requirement: "Your program will use one array of type Library to store all information read from the input
file." A Library is a class, Music, Book, and Movie are sublcasses. Then each of those have subclasses.

Comment: why don't you use Collections framework ? in this case may be a List. here's a sorting method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List). you can also use `Arrays.toString(myLibrary)` or `Arrays.deepToString(myLibrary)`, to print the array all at once. chk this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java

Comment: That does not make sense from a date model perspective. Music, Book and Movie are not Libraries. A Library is a collection of Music, Book and Movie and you can introduce a base class for Music, Book and Movie, like Title or whatsoever

Comment: I have to follow the requirements. "At the top level you will have a class called Library. Library will have three subclasses: Music, Book, and Movie. Music will have two subclasses: Song and Album. Book will have two subclasses: Fiction and Nonfiction. Movie, Fiction, Nonfiction, Song, and Album will not have any subclasses."

Comment: `This is for a CS-101 course. I don't feel I should need to use Comparable.` CS-101 course is not a criteria to use `Comparable` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to defining `print()` method for `Library`; You can try following:

```
public void printLibrary (Library [] libraryArray) {
    for(Library library :  libraryArray) 
        library.print();
}
```

or if you overload `toString()` for `Library` you can simply use:

```
public void printLibrary (Library [] libraryArray) {
    for(Library library :  libraryArray) 
        System.out.println(library);
}
```

And the calling will be done like:

```
Library myLibrary[] = new Library[100];
printLibrary(myLibrary);
```

**EDIT:**

To sort the array you should implement `Comparable<Library>` in `Library` class and simply use

```
Arrays.sort(myLibrary);
```

to sort the array.

Comment: I think this might be the best answer so far, let me consider this. Thanks much!

Comment: I guess before I go ahead and mark it. How would I go about sorting this array then? I would need to call some kind of `myLibrary.sort()` method. But where would I define that method?

Comment: Technically that's another question but I will answer as well.

Comment: @ardavis if you go an updating the question with new stuff; answering it makes it really difficult. Please ask separate questions.

Comment: I was updating with background information. Many of the answers have been outside the scope of the task. So I felt more clarification was necessary. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just added another answer to summarize.

Answer (score 0):

myLibrary is an array of type Library.  It doesn't have the method print.  You should try something like:

```
Library myLibrary[] = new Library[100];
myLibrary[0] = new Library();    
myLibrary[0].print();
```

Comment: Okay, so this is what I was thinking. I was thinking each "Library" would have a print method. But is it possible to have a "print" method on the entire Library?

Comment: but this is what @Hernan says (and what you also have implemented) - you do have the print method on the entire library. Try thinking of your data model - what do you want to model? A collection of libraries? Or Library as a collection of Titles?

Answer (score 0):

you are actually calling print method from Library type Array and you should call print method from  Library type object(not Library type Array).

```
public class Library {
    // Constructor

    public Library() {
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Library Sorted by Title");
    }
}

public class MediaManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Library myLibrary[] = new Library[100];
        for (Library lb : myLibrary) {
            lb.print();
        }
    }
}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a print method in Library class, it means you can call that method in each Library object, but you point at an array of Library instead of each library, what you can to do to print all array's object is :

```
Library myLibrary[] = new Library[100];
for(Library library : myLibrary){ 
    library.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the discussions above, a more suited data model would look like this:

```
public class Library {
   private Vector<Title> allTitles;

   public void print() {
     // Print all titles from the vector
     for(Title t : allTitles) {
        t.print();
     }
   }
}

public abstract class Title {
   public abstract void print();
}

public class Movie extends Title {
   public void print() {
      ... // print the Movie
   }
}

public class Music extends Title {
   public void print() {
      ... // print the Music
   }
}

public class Book extends Title {
   public void print() {
      ... // print the Book
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bound to add another answer post the question is updated twice from original question:

> UPDATE
>
> Requirements from my assignment: "Your program will use one array of type Library to store all information read from the input file."
>   "At the top level you will have a class called Library. Library will have three subclasses: Music, Book, and Movie. Music will have two subclasses: Song and Album. Book will have two subclasses: Fiction and Nonfiction. Movie, Fiction, Nonfiction, Song, and Album will not have any subclasses."
>
> UPDATE 2
>
> This is for a CS-101 course. I don't feel I should need to use Comparable.

The best solution seems:

A. Create class structure as defined in your problem.

```
class Library {...}
class Music extends Library {...}
class Book extends Library {...}
class Movie extends Library {...}
class Song extends Music {...}
class Album extends Music {...}
class Fiction extends Book {...}
class NonFiction extends Book {...}
```

B. Override `toString()` method in each class.

C. Simply use a `for-each` loop and print the objects.

```
for(Library library :  libraryArray) 
    System.out.println(library);
```

D. **You have to use `Comparable` or `Comparator` in case you want the `Array` to be ordered/sorted; there is no other way.**

Comment: In my `MediaManager` file, I will just write a method, `public void printLibrary(Library[] library)` and loop through the library calling the `print()` method then. Thus avoiding `Comparable` and `Comparator`.

Comment: `Comparable` or `Comparator` are for Sorting and not printing. :)

Comment: Oops, right. I meant I would write `public Library[] sortLibrary(Library[] library)` and I would then do a sorting algorithm on it, such as Bubble Sort, etc.

Comment: If you want to re-invent the wheel go ahead... **`Comparable` and `Comparator` tells you how two objects are compared no matter what algorithm you use.** Understand them as `>` operator between `a[i]>a[j]` part of bubble sort.