# Sorting an array of custom objects by values in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am working on a CS-101 assignment and am only allowed to use a single array. I have an array that looks like the following:

```
[Song, Song, Album, Fiction, Movie, Nonfiction, Song]
```

Here is the hierarchy for background (requirements from my assignment):

> "At the top level you will have a class called Library. Library will have three subclasses: Music, Book, and Movie. Music will have two subclasses: Song and Album. Book will have two subclasses: Fiction and Nonﬁction. Movie, Fiction, Nonﬁction, Song,
>   and Album will not have any subclasses."

I am currently trying to write a method that will sort the Books by their ISBN number. So Fiction and Nonfiction are subclasses of my Book class, which is a subclass of Library.

I hold everything in `Library myLibrary[] = new Library[100];`

I'm not sure how to go about retrieving the ISBN's from the Books only and sort them since I am only allowed one array; otherwise I would love to make an array of Books, then sort those separately.

What are some hints / algorithms that I can utilize to accomplish this?

*Update*

I can post more code if needed. But this question is currently more focused on the approach.

Comment: once Books are sorted do you care where Music and Movie are in the array?

Comment: Not at this point. I'll have a separate method for sorting those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying to give the actual implementation of the algorithm, you should do an in-place sort where priority can be done by:

**1.** Books have more priority than Music and Movies

**2.** If two objects are Books then priority is based on ISBN

Comment: So maybe sort the entire library by first placing the Books at the front? Then only sorting the objects if they are `instanceof Book`?

Comment: I meant while sorting you are already moving the Books to the front, take a look at in-place Quicksort

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because this is what I utilized for my homework. The other answers may also be correct.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is setting up your inheritance correctly and than implementing the Comparable interface.  See here for example: [Java Comaprable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/java-class-implements-comparable) and than calling .sort on your array of your parent type (in your case this would be myLibrary.sort();)  Here is an example of how sort works on primitive types: [Primitive type array sort](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_SortArray.html)

So

1. Implement Comaparable on your subtypes
2. Create your array of the parent type and populate it
3. call sort on your array.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works or not. (currently on tab so could not run code)

[I think after sorting your books will be saturated towards one side of the array. Please let me know the result]

```
/* book sorting is in decreasing order of ISBN, followed by non book items
The books will be at the beginning of array, other items towards the end */
Arrays.sort(myLibrary, new Comparator<Library>()
    {
        int compare(Library l1, Library l2){
            //if both are books then compare ISBN and return appropriate
            if((l1 instanceof Book) && (l2 instanceof Book)){
                Book b1=(Book)l1; Book b2=(Book)l2;
                if(b1.getISBN()<b2.getISBN) {
                    return -1;
                } else if(b1.getISBN()>b2.getISBN()) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else {//if either one, or none are Book

                //if only l1 is Book, l2 is not
                if(l1 instanceof Book){
                    return 1;
                }

                //if only l2 is Book, l1 is not
                if(l2 instanceof Book){
                    return -1;
                }

                //none are Book
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: So every non-book item is equal to every book? That can't be correct. (For one thing, it violates the requirement that `x.compareTo(y) == 0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))` for all `z`. Let `x` and `z` be distinct books and let `y` be a non-book item.) Note that this can be fixed by always returning `1` or `-1` whenever exactly one of `l1` and `l2` is a `Book`.

Comment: But `l1,l2` are Library references and it's not necessary that `Library` has `ISBN` attribute; it's specific to `Book`.

Comment: Sorry, the Library instances need to be cast to Book objects before comparing ISBN numbers.

I edited the code to reflect the changes. It will work now imo..

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

As mentioned in the [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489128/custom-methods-for-an-array-of-custom-objects-in-java/12489176#12489176) Write a new `Comparator` and use the same for comparing `Library` objects.

*Note: I haven't checked for null but you should do so...*

```
class LibraryComparator implements Comparator<Library> {
    public int compare(Library l1, Library l2){
         // If Both are Book instance do the comparison
         if(l1 instanceof Book && l2 instanceof Book){
              // Assuming ISBN is a String or Long field in your class Book
              return ((Book)l1).getISBN().compareTo(((Book)l2).getISBN());
         } else {
         // Otherwise no change in ordering
              return 0;
              // You could specify sorting logic for Movie and Music here as well
         }
    }
}
```

And then you can sort the array like:

```
Arrays.sort(myLibrary, new LibraryComparator());
```